# I cannot enable hibernate in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, hibernate

I changed the config following [this article on enabling hibernate](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-14-04/) in Ubuntu 14.04, but nothing has changed and I cannot see a hibernate option. The steps are as follows:

> To re-enable hibernate, run the commands below one by one to edit the
>   config file:
>
> ```
> sudo -i
>
> cd /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/
>
> gedit com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
> ```
>
> *Tips: if the config file does not work for you, try another one by changing /var/lib to /etc in the code.*
>
> Copy and paste below lines into the file and save it.
>
> ```
> [Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
> Identity=unix-user:*
> Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
> ResultActive=yes
>
> [Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
> Identity=unix-user:*
> Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
> ResultActive=yes
> ```
>
> Restart your computer and done.

How I can enable hibernate?

Comment: Do you have enough swap space for hibernate?

Comment: Yes  I have and I test my system with sudo pm-hibernate and everything is okey